# Подскажите хорошие инструменты для создания скринов

Tags: скриншот

Нужен хороший сервис или программа, которая качественно делает скрины.
Существующие имеют ряд недостатков: у некоторых версия браузеров настолько стара, что некоторые элементы сайта вообще отсутствуют. Раньше скринил через какое-то расширение в мозилле. Сейчас скрины через него сильно размываются и теряют качество.

Answer (score 1):

Вот я [этим](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) в Chrome пользуюсь, если скринить сайты.
А если просто скрины экрана делать, то с помощью Яндекс.Диск.